# Return to main code

Tags: c#

I have just written a simple code in C# for displaying a message which takes your input as hours of sleep and based on that returns whether you are well rested or no.

The problem is whenever you type anything other than a integer it throws an exception so I have tried to handle this by using try and catch method.
I want my code to return to the evaluation again after I have entered the integer correctly next time. How can I amend my code to do this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("your name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("how many hours of sleep did you get");

            try
            {
                int hoursOfSleep = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("hello " + name);

                if (hoursOfSleep > 8)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you are well rested");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you need sleep");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Hours !! ");
                Console.WriteLine(" Enter hours in integer");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `int.TryParse` and check it's valid integer or not instead of throwing an exception. Then you can want an input until you get a valid one with a `while` statement.

Comment: From catch call your main method again like Main(new []{string.Empty}).

Comment: @Mukund thats strange and unnecessary. Simple loop is enough.

Comment: @Mukund This is a really awful solution..

Comment: I thought as he is new to the programming, this will be very simple solution to make code correct and then he can think more on top of that for other solution. Anyway my apology @Oscar

Comment: @Mukund as he is new, he should learn to code correctly and don't do awful things

Answer (score 8):

instead of `try...catch` block use loop and `TryParse` method of `int`

```
int hoursOfSleep;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out hoursOfSleep)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Hours !! ");
    Console.WriteLine(" Enter hours in integer");
}

Console.WriteLine("hello " + name);

if (hoursOfSleep > 8)
{
    Console.WriteLine("you are well rested");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("you need sleep");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try wrapping the try-catch in something like

```
while(Console.Readline() != "q")
{
... your code here ...

}
```

then you application will continue until you type q and hit enter